# How to reload a react component without using any event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, dom-events

Is it possible to reload a component in react without using the help of a function like onClick. I want my component to reload again after it just got loaded.

I tried using 
`window.location.reload(false);` in the constructor. I even tried using `useEffect()` but they make the page reload infinitely.

Is there any work around?

Comment: If you want it to reload immediately after loading then it sounds like your objective is an infinite loop?

Comment: I have passed a value as a prop to a child component which loads on the page. This value is calculated before it gets passed. I want the value to be recalculated after user performs an action on the child component. I figured auto reloading the page would solve my issue.

Comment: Ok that much makes sense, what is the action?

Comment: addition of a cookie in the browser. I'm not using any node module, simple javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people accomplish this by setting a dummy setState method that is strictly used to trigger a refresh.  Consider this component:

```
export const Proof = () => {
    console.log("Component re-rendered")
    const [dummyState,rerender] = React.useState(1);

    const onClick = () => {
        rerender(dummyState + 1);
    }

    React.useEffect( () => {
        console.log("dummyState's state has updated to: " + dummyState)
    }, [dummyState])
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}>reRender</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Whenever you want to rerender the component you just need to trigger a change in the dummyState.  Clicking the button will cause the components state to change, which will cause the component to rerender (i used a console.log() for proof). It is worth noting that simply calling a method that instantly changes the state of the component will result in an infinite loop.

From reading your comment above, it sounds like you are passing a value as a prop to a child component and you would like the value to be recalculated as soon as any interaction with that component occurs.  Ideally, the interaction itself should cause the recalculation.  But if you would just like to quickly recalculate the value and rerender the component as soon as it renders then i think this would work:

```
export const Proof = () => {
    console.log("Component re-rendered")
    const [dummyState,rerender] = React.useState(1);

    //the empty brackets will cause this useEffect 
    //statement to only execute once.
    React.useEffect( () => {
        rerender(dummyState + 1);
    }, []) 

    return(
        <div>
            <p>dummyState</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

You could also recalculate the value in the useEffect method, as it will get called as soon as the component initially renders but not on any subsequent rerenders (due to the empty brackets as the second parameter to the useEffect method)

Comment: My apologies.  I should have been more detailed. I have edited my comment.  Does this help?

Comment: hey. Thanks for the updated solution. I'm relatively new to react so sorry if I'm missing out on something but I end up with an error saying I cant use hooks in a class based component.

Comment: That is correct. Class based components do not integrate with the Hooks API.  You will need to convert your class based component to a functional component.

See: https://scotch.io/tutorials/5-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-w-react-hooks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter some dependecies to your useEffect hook ? 
Like :

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello');
 }, [isLoad];
```

Here you're component will re-render only if `isLoad` is changing.